Zero Access Encryption on AWS, Azure or Google Cloud possible with MongoDB?
I'm having a question about the following: is it possible in general to store data on a cloud platform, specifically either AWS, Azure or Google Cloud, without the cloud provider itself being able to access the data at any time? Similar to Proton's "Zero Access Encryption"?
I've seen that data at rest encryption is possible with associated Key Management Services, but the keys eventually still reside in the control of the respective cloud provider, aren't they?
Is it possible to avoid that?

you can encrypt the data, before storing it and after receiving decrypt it againa.

@nbk Client-side encryption, right? Therefore, any attempts of performing calculations on the data in the cloud becomes void, correct? Does this approach have caveats for multiple devices in sync, e.g. desktop and mobile?

Yes only client side, as every communication can be read by the provider.  Using Maui and c# you can write a program that will run every where

It depends. You can host the encrypted data and the keys at different providers, see KMS Providers
